# how to print \" in C++

Tags: c++, printing, ofstream, quotations

I need to print a string that says exactly:

```
std::string("-I\"/path/to/dir\" ");
```

Basically, I need to do this because I am using C++ code to generate C++ code.

I want to write the above string via an ofstream, so something like

```
 ofstream fout;
 fout << the_string << endl;
```

The problem is that I cannot do `\\"` inside a string.

Comment: Yes, you can do \\\ inside a string. What makes you think you can't?

Comment: If you want to do \", type in `\\\\#`.

Comment: @muntoo: `"\\\\#"` would just print `"\\#"` ?

Comment: @sehe `\\\\ ` in the question will print `\\ `. (Without the code tags.) Now, the question is, how do you print `\\\\ ` without the extra space with code markup in comments?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Just escape the slash *as well as* the quotes! I.e. `\"` --> `\\\"`

```
fout << "std::string(\"-I\\\"/path/to/dir\\\" \");" << std::endl;
```

in C++0x/C++11

```
fout << R"(std::string("-I\"/path/to/dir\" ");)" << std::endl;
```

which uses a **[*raw string literal*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C++11#New_string_literals)**<sup>1</sup>

#### *See both versions tested live at http://ideone.com/TgtZK*

<sub><sup>1</sup> For which unsurprisingly the syntax highlighters for ideone.com and stackoverflow are not yet prepared :)</sub>

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
  cout << "std::string(\"-I\\\"/path/to/dir\\\" \");" << endl;
  return 0;
}
```

printing

```
std::string("-I\"/path/to/dir\" ");
```

The point is: you need to escape both the slash and the quote.

Answer (score 0):

I hope I understood your question correctly:

Escape `\` and escape `"`:

`\\\"`

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna try to put additional "/" character, because the single "/" will not be parsed as string. I think it should work (I'm Java/C# guy, and I have encountered this problem myself couple of times).

Answer (score 0):

This works as an answer to the title question even it's not your issue :

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    std::string foo = string(" /!\\ WARNING /!\\ -> 1");
    cout << foo << endl;
    cout << " /!\\ WARNING /!\\ -> 2" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output of this is :

> /!\ WARNING /!\ -> 1
>
> /!\ WARNING /!\ -> 2

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).